# QGIS - Python Action Error

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins, osgeo4w, actions

I am using QGIS 3.18.1-Zürich and I am trying to create a Python action. Although I have installed the required packages, I get an error as shown below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 2, in 
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 799, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

Python path:

```
'C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python', 
'C:/Users/User/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\\profiles\\default/python', 
'C:/Users/User/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\\profiles\\default/python/plugins', 
'C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins', 
'C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\Python37', 
'C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\Python37\\Scripts', 
'C:\\OSGeo4W64\\bin\\python37.zip', 
'C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\Python37\\DLLs', 
'C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\Python37\\lib', 
'C:\\OSGeo4W64\\bin', 
'C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages', 
'C:/Users/User/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\\profiles\\default/python'
```

**What can I do to solve this problem?**

Edit:
I have already installed `pandas` in Python 3.9 but QGIS is using 3.7.

```
WARNING: Value for scheme.headers does not match. Please report this to <https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9617>
distutils: c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\UNKNOWN
sysconfig: c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include
WARNING: Additional context:
user = False
home = None
root = None
prefix = None
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (1.2.4)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7.3 in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.3 in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2021.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.16.5 in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (1.20.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7.3->pandas) (1.15.0)
WARNING: Value for scheme.headers does not match. Please report this to <https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9617>
distutils: c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\UNKNOWN
sysconfig: c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include
WARNING: Additional context:
user = False
home = None
root = None
prefix = None
```

Comment: But the error denies your claim that you have installed the required packages. It says "you didn't install `pandas`".

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz I have edited the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

QGIS uses the Python environment installed by itself. You have to install packages to Python 3.7 installed by QGIS installation.

- Open OSGeo Shell
- Run `py3_env`
- Run `pip install pandas`